# How do I return false if a value in an array isn't contained in another array?

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I have two arrays. One being the input user array and the other being the Array of choices. An example is the user array is BLACK, RED, GREEN and the choices array is BLUE,RED,GREEN. Because BLACK isn't in the choices array it would return false. You could also have RED,RED,RED return True as red is contained in the choices array, it doesn't matter how many times you use the choice.

Here is my current code but isTrue only ever goes up once for some reason and I don't think it accounts for having multiple choices of the same colour. I feel there has to be an easier way to do this?

```
public Boolean isValidColour(String userInput) {
        ArrayList<String> userPegsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] userPegs = userInput.toUpperCase().split(",");
        int isTrue = 0;
        for (String peg: userPegs) {
            userPegsArray.add(peg);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <Peg.values().length; i++) {
            for (String peg:userPegsArray) {
                if(peg.equals(Peg.valueOf(i).toString())) {
                    isTrue += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isTrue == 5) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Update: Solved, thanks for the help in comments.

SOLUTION

```
    public Boolean isValidColour(String userInput) {
        ArrayList<String> userPegsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] userPegs = userInput.toUpperCase().split(",");
        for (String peg: userPegs) {
            userPegsArray.add(peg);
        }

        Map pegMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Peg.values().length; i++) {
            pegMap.put(Peg.valueOf(i).toString(), i);
        }

        for (String peg:userPegs) {
            System.out.println("Peg: " + peg + " | pegMap: " + pegMap.toString());
            if (pegMap.containsKey(peg)) {
                System.out.println("ayyyayay");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note please

```java
    public Boolean isValidColour(String userInput) {
        List<String> userPegsArray = Arrays.asList(userInput.toUpperCase().split(","));
        return Peg.containsAll(userPegsArray);
    }
```

Comment: The issue with that is the userPegsArray might not have all the elements of the other array. For example they might have the same element cloned 5 times but that would still return true in my case.

Comment: @Alexander Bishop I don't understand your comment. You need to be clearer presenting the problem. If you have RED, RED, RED in your user array, does the choices array need to have 3 REDs in order to return true? If choices array only needs to have one RED in order to return true, yeahseol's answer is correct.

Comment: Well that is correct, it only needs one Red. I think maybe the issue is that it is expecting the user array to contain all the choices at least once, that is not the case for my problem in that a user can choose just one choice from the choice array and use any others. Think of it almost like a dictionary of approved words and the user types a sentence, if they don't use one of the approved words thats fine, but if they use a word not on the list then it returns false.